# JQuery if condition

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have this jQuery code which I want it to run in a given condition. Now I have 2 strings `file` and `stat` and I want to run a block of code only if both of them are not empty. That means one can be empty and both of them can be filled but 2 of them mustn't be empty so I ran this:

```
if((stat !== "") || (file !== "")) {
    console.log("good");
}
```

But the code doesn't run until I fill in both fields. I also changed the `OR` to `&&` and still same result. Is it that `||` and `&&` give the same command or is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: This should definitely work. Please check out your actual contents of your variables using `console.log(stat, file)`.

Comment: I checked them out and I get their values in the console.log which signifies that they are not empty

Comment: In that case there's no way you can't get "good" in your console. Could you edit your OP to include the values and make a jsfiddle with them?

Comment: I am confused... Do you only want to run the code when both are filled in or run it if at least one of the two is filled in?

Comment: Are you specifying a default value when you declare the "stat" and "file" variables? i.e. var stat = ""? It could be that they are declared, but not assigned to meaning they are "undefined".

Comment: I want to run to run it if both are filled or at least one is filled

Comment: Who deleted the first answer by James. I tried it and it worked. Any reason for deleting the answer?

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE James himself deleted it because he got downvoted since negating an `&&` is no different than doing an `||`. You must have fixed your issue elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks to all, but I have gotten my answer from the first answer by James. I don't really knew why it got a downvotedown vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below one

```
    if((typeof stat != 'undefined') || (typeof file != 'undefined')) {
        console.log("good");
    }
```

Or

```
    if((stat != '') || (file != '')) {
        console.log("good");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
var stat="";
var file="";



if((!!stat || !!file)) {
  console.log("good");
}else{
  console.log("bad");
}
```

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the opposite approach:

```
 if (!stat && !file) {} else {console.log("good")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ((stat.length != 0) || (file.length != 0)) {
alert('ok');
}
```